# Mule choice using XPath Evaluator

Tags: mule

In the following mule flow I'm using xpath to decide which queue the message needs to be sent to. However the xpath expression is returning false, even though the XML has tc="121". Can you tell what am I doing wrong?

Below is the mule flow and XML evaluated by XPath.

Mule Flow :

```
<flow name="ProcessXMLRequest">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queue="mq.xml.request" />
    <logger message="XML payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" />
    <choice>
        <when expression="/TXLife/TXLifeRequest/TransType/@tc='121'"
            evaluator="xpath">
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="mq.121.request.apps" />
        </when>
        <when
            expression="/TXLife/TXLifeRequest/TransType/@tc='1122'"
            evaluator="xpath">
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="mq.1122.request.apps" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="mq.error"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

XML:

```
<TXLife xmlns:ns2="http://abc.com/services/mvi" xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
    <TXLifeRequest PrimaryObjectID="Holding_1">
        <TransType tc="121">121</TransType>
        <TransMode tc="2">2</TransMode>
    </TXLifeRequest>
</TXLife>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a namespace issue: you need to configure the `http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2` namespace and use it in your XPath expression.

In Mule, this is achieved with the [namespace manager](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/XML+Namespaces) in such way:

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager>
  <mulexml:namespace prefix="life2" uri="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```